# IIS redirect example.com to www.example.com

Tags: iis, redirection

Under IIS, is there a simple way for me to configure my site such that all requests to `http://example.com` will forward to `http://www.example.com` ?

I'm using Microsoft Management Console 3.0, it doesn't specify the IIS version plainly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the "host header" feature: http://www.visualwin.com/host-header/